# For $p = 2, 3, 5, 7$ compute $Maps(\mathbf{Z}[\omega], \mathbf{F}_p)$ and $Maps(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}], \mathbf{F}_p)$

Tags: ring-theory

And then I have to deduce that no homomorphisms exist between $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ and $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. I've computed that 2 and 3 are not prime, 5 and 7 are prime in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and 2 and 5 prime, 5 and 7 not prime in $\mathbf{Z}[\omega]$ in an earlier part of the problem but I'm not really sure how this helps me if it even does at all. I'm not even sure how I can characterize every single homomorphism or if they're supposed to be unique. I'm more or less struggling to grasp what exactly the problem demands from me, as well as how to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one direction, the other is entirely analogous: Suppose that there exists some ring homomorphism
$$\varphi:\ \Bbb{Z}[\omega]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}].$$
Then for any prime number $p$, any group homomorphism $\psi:\ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_p$ gives rise to a group homomorphism $\psi'=\psi\circ\varphi$ by composition. For example, the ring homomorphism
$$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_2:\ a+b\sqrt{-2}\ \longmapsto\ a,$$
then yields a ring homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{F}_2$. But there is no such ring homomorphism, and hence there does not exist a ring homomorphism $\varphi:\ \Bbb{Z}[\omega]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Comment: I guess I'm still mostly hung up on the original question, I'm not exactly sure what it is even asking me to be honest